# Add element to several associations automatically

Tags: associations

I'm trying to add a certain element (`testKey`) to several already existing associations `testAssoc1` and `testAssoc2` by looping over the associations and using `AssociateTo`.

```
testAssoc1 = Association@{"key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2};
testAssoc2 = Association@{"key2" -> 1, "key2" -> 2};

Do[
  AssociateTo[assoc,"testKey"->3],
  {assoc,{testAssoc1,testAssoc2}}
];

testAssoc1
testAssoc2
```

Unfortunately, this strategy doesn't seem to work, as `testKey` is not added to the predefined associations so I have to update them manually piece by piece.

Can anyone tell me, what I am missing? Is there some neat solution for my problem? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
testAssoc1 = Association@{"key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2};
testAssoc2 = Association@{"key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2};

Append[#, "testKey" -> 3 ] & /@ {testAssoc1, testAssoc2}
```

> ```
> {<|"key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2, "testKey" -> 3|>, <|"key1" -> 1, 
>   "key2" -> 2, "testKey" -> 3|>}
> ```

**edit**
If you want to update the associations as well:

```
{testAssoc1, testAssoc2} = 
 Append[#, "testKey" -> 3 ] & /@ {testAssoc1, testAssoc2}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! That solves my problem!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `testAssoc1` and `testAssoc2` evaluate prematurely. You could try:

```
testAssoc1 = Association@{"key1"->1,"key2"->2};
testAssoc2 = Association@{"key2"->1,"key2"->2};

Replace[
    Unevaluated @ {testAssoc1,testAssoc2},
    s_ :> AssociateTo[s,"testKey"->3],
    {1}
];

testAssoc1
testAssoc2
```

> <|"key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2, "testKey" -> 3|>

> <|"key2" -> 2, "testKey" -> 3|>